# Implement socket.io-client in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement socket.io-client in swift. It is not working as supposed. I am unable to read any response from the server on my request. My socket is connecting but after that, I am unable to call events and getting their response.
 Swift 4, Xcode 10

I am using a global class to declare socket functions as 'clsGlobal' and calling socket functions in different viewcontrollers.

import Foundation
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class clsSocket: NSObject {

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

static var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "my url")!, config: [.log(true), .reconnects(true)])
static var socket = manager.defaultSocket

static func ConnectSocket(){


    socket.connect()
    print(socket.status)

    socket.on("locationsUpdate", callback: { data,ack in
        print(data)
        let resp = data[0] as! Any
        print(resp)
    })
}
static func updateLocation(dId:NSNumber, uId:NSNumber, distance:Double){
    let datafield : [String:Any] = ["id":dId,
                                    "userid": uId,
                                    "travelledDistance":distance
    ]
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: datafield)
    if socket.status == .connected {
        socket.emit("updateLocation",  data!)
        socket.emit("requestLocations")
    }

}
static func dogDisconnect(dogid:NSNumber, userid:NSNumber){
    let datafield = ["dId":did, "uId":userid]
    let dataobj = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: datafield)
    socket.emit("disconnect",  dataobj!)
    socket.disconnect()
    socket.off("requestLocations")
}
```

}

How to know if the server is connected and how to print response from server?

Comment: try socket.onAny { response in }, else look for error in your connection params. My connection is manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: APIConfigs.apiURL)!, config: [.log(false), .reconnects(true), .connectParams(["token": token])])

Comment: I have tried this but didn't worked.

Comment: didn't connected? may be problems on server?

Comment: I updated the structure... still not working.

Comment: why all methods are static? why don't you set token in init?

Comment: static methods for I need to call them in another view controllers, and I don't really need to set the 'token'. edited.

Comment: try create singleton, and check server response

Comment: finally got response. thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a Global for socket Class

```
import SocketIO

class SocketHelper {

    static let shared = SocketHelper()
    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: AppUrls.socketURL)!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

    private init() {
        socket = manager.defaultSocket
    }

    func connectSocket(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> () ) {
        disconnectSocket()
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {[weak self] (data, ack) in
            print("socket connected")
            self?.socket.removeAllHandlers()
            completion(true)
        }
        socket.connect()
    }

    func disconnectSocket() {
        socket.removeAllHandlers()
        socket.disconnect()
        print("socket Disconnected")
    }

    func checkConnection() -> Bool {
        if socket.manager?.status == .connected {
            return true
        }
        return false

    }

    enum Events {

        case search

        var emitterName: String {
            switch self {
            case .searchTags:
                return "emt_search_tags"
            }
        }

        var listnerName: String {
            switch self {
            case .search:
                return "filtered_tags"
            }
        }

        func emit(params: [String : Any]) {
            SocketHelper.shared.socket.emit(emitterName, params)
        }

        func listen(completion: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {
            SocketHelper.shared.socket.on(listnerName) { (response, emitter) in
                completion(response)
            }
        }

        func off() {
            SocketHelper.shared.socket.off(listnerName)
        }
    }
}
```

How to use

Connect Socket using this code

```
SocketHelper.shared.connectSocket { (success) in

}
```

Start Listen event

```
SocketHelper.Events.search.listen { [weak self] (result) in
    // print(result[0])
}
```

Emit Event

```
SocketHelper.Events.search.emit(params: <--Your Params-->)
```

Comment: I am not getting any data in callback, but I am getting data in log.

Comment: So, whenever you goes to a screen, you need to call ```SocketHelper.shared.connectSocket { (success) in

}``` in `viewDidLoad`? Or just call once in AppDeleage?

Comment: If you want throughout app then appDelegate, and screen specific viewDidload

Comment: Lisner not working anything that you guys faced it @RonakAdeshara Thanks

Comment: may be url issue can be there

Comment: Hi @RonakAdeshara thanks for your answer, can you write a update to your answer and add token to socket connection i really need and I cannot find example to this

Answer (score 4):

Please remember that the socketio client in swift is not yet compatible with js socket.io version `3.x.x` (as of 1/21/2021).

This was an issue we came across since we were using the latest socketio version in our node server (`3.1.0`). The client will be able to initially connect but will not be able to receive any messages emitted from the server.

We solved our problem by downgrading our server to socketio version `2.4.1`

Answer (score -1):

The answer of the author Ronak Adeshara is correct, I try the following code below and it can handle the event sent from the socket server.

```
// connect to socket server and listen to the event
SocketHelper.shared.connectSocket { (success) in
  SocketHelper.Events.search.listen { [weak self] (result) in
    // print(result[0])
  } 
}

SocketHelper.Events.search.emit(params: <--Your Params-->)
```